# Firebase Database to be only accessed by specific domain

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, firebase-storage

I am trying to figure out a way to make my realtime database & storage to only be accessed by specific domain.

For example if my web is hosted on domain with the name www.xyz.com then the data can only be accessed from that specific website and not anywhere else.
Can anyone help me with the rule for that?

P.S I am not looking forward to restricting it to specific kind of email i need to restrict it to the domain name.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you read the answers in the duplicate question? did you try setting up similar rules for your own situation? it does seem like a duplicate question.

Comment: @vsync in my case that wont work since I am using anonymous Login.

Comment: and only now you are mentioning this critical information regarding your question? `anonymous login`..? you should have said so in the title.

Comment: you can and should ask Firebase directly on their forums or whatever